# Escaping ampersand (&) in Windows batch script used to map/connect network drives

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe, escape-characters

Using a simple batch file to connect to network drives on Windows start-up but one of the folder names contains an ampersand and I cannot for the life of me, figure out how to escape it.

Here is the command:-

```
net use P: \\SERVER\Path\Applications & Software
```

I have tried:-

```
net use P: \\SERVER\Path\"Applications & Software"
net use P: \\SERVER\Path\"Applications ^& Software"
net use P: \\SERVER\Path\"Applications ^^& Software"
net use P: "\\SERVER\Path\"Applications & Software"
net use P: "\\SERVER\Path\Applications ^& Software"
```

No matter what is tried, it just spews out that the particular command has a syntax error. All other drives are mapping/connecting fine (within the same batch file).

Can anyone advise what is needed to map/connect a drive with a folder name that contains an ampersand like the above?

Comment: If you're going to downvote, please comment with the reason why...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to escape the ampersand in a double-quoted string. It appears you intended to try this, but there is a typo in your fourth attempt. Correct is: `net use P: "\\SERVER\Path\Applications & Software"` (without the quotes in the middle).

Comment: Doh. Thank you, that worked perfectly. I could have sworn I had tried every possible combination! :D